# The electromagnetic Stress Tensor (Einstein Notation)

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have the tensor defined by

$\Xi^{\alpha \beta } = \frac{1}{\mu_0}(F^{\alpha}_\gamma F^{\gamma\beta}+\frac{1}{4}n^{\alpha\beta} F_{\mu\gamma} F^{\mu\gamma})$

My problem is with the notation $F^{\alpha}_\gamma $, what does this represent and is there a way to convert it to either $F^{\alpha\gamma} $ or $F_{\alpha\gamma} $.

Thank you!

This is because I am trying to get the divergence of $\Xi^{\alpha \beta }$ and show it is equal to $-F^{\beta\gamma}J_{\gamma}$

(I have all the answers of the different parts as it is a proof in my notes  but I'm having problems with the steps in-between)

Comment: Have you considered the metric?

Comment: No, what is that?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you are studying the EM stress tensor without having even learned about the metric tensor. I suggest you go back to beginning tensor calculus before going forwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F^\alpha_\gamma$ is the usual EM stress tensor $F^{\alpha\gamma}$ with the $\gamma$ index lowered. This is accomplished using the following identity:

$$F^\alpha_\gamma=g_{\gamma\mu}F^{\alpha\mu}$$

where $g$ is the metric tensor.